# Wrong amount for item in Quote and Order

Tags: magento

Hi i have a question regarding tax_amount, row_total, price_incl_tax and row_total_incl_tax.

My problem is that those values are caclulated as follow:

```
price = 30 
price_excl_tax = 25.08
```

so for ex: price_incl_tax should be 30, but it is 25.08...
base_tax amount is good, it's calculated from price (30), but tax_amount is calculated from price_excl_tax

Did someone encoutered this issue ?

Comment: Why should price_excl_tax be 30? Is tax 0? Please show some more data

Comment: price_excl_tax = 25.08, where do You have 30 ? And tax is 19.6%
So price_excl_tax is good, but not price_incl_tax and as follow: row_total, tax_amount, row_total_incl_tax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like it isn't problem with Magento itsefl, but with Thread Interference on PHP side.